# How to build project statically to remove vcruntime140.dll dependency?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, openssl, windows-runtime

Upgraded a project with openssl from vs2013 to vs2017. The project works as intended post building without any errors from visual studio.

Problem is the dependency on the vcruntime140.dll when I export the built exe of the project to a virtual machine(Windows Server 2012r2 x64) to check the behavior.

I have set the project to be built in Release|Win32|\Multi Threaded(\MT). With this I expected the exe to not require the vcruntime140.dll but this is not the case.

Additional Dependencies in the project configuration is: libcrypto.lib;libssl.lib;ws2_32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

The openssl library is built using: "perl Configure Win-32"

what am I missing here?

Comment: While not a solution to your problem, you could install the redistributable on the target machine. This is a common practice.

Comment: Use [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to check dependencies up front. Perhaps one of your dependencies drags in the vcruntime140 dll.

Comment: I tried with only placing the vcruntime140.dll in the directory and was able to run the exe without any errors. if any solution doesn't come up unfortunately this is what I will have to roll with

Comment: @Botje should I try running dependency walker on the 2012r2 machine or any where should be fine?

Comment: If you are dynamically linked to libcrypto.lib or libssl.lib, they will still need the vcruntime140.dll in the directory. Deploying vcruntime140.dll should be a good solution.

Comment: If your application should be distributed more widely, always create an installer for it (and it might be a good idea for more narrow distributions, like internally within a corporation too). Then that installer could make sure that the VC redistributable is installed, if needed.

Comment: well screw me, dependency walker clearly says libcrypto.dll needs the vcruntime140.dll. This tool is a boon